# List and upload to Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am trying to learn a simple web app (PHP) using Google drive API.

1. Display list of files in the drive.
2. Add a new file to the drive.

Code as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();

$url_array = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = $url_array[0];

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(''); // Kept my id
$client->setClientSecret(''); //kept my key
$client->setRedirectUri($url);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

 if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
 $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
 header('location:'.$url);exit;
 } elseif (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {
 $client->authenticate();
 }
```

It works fine till here. The app gets authenticated and redirects back to my app.
Now, I try displaying list of files.

Problem code:

```
 $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
 $result = array();
  $files = $service->files->listFiles();
  $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
 print_r($result);
```

I get this error:

> Error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files: (401) Login Required' in C:\wamp\www\Sample\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php

Can someone please help in correcting me and also I would be thankful in sharing simple code how to insert a doc.

Comment: Does a "logged in" state require `setClientId` and `setClientSecret` to be called, or does it require the execution of `authenticate` as well? Is the latter called (i.e. is your `code` query string populated and correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line after $client->authenticate();:
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);